# Need help fixing clan

Tags: clash-of-clans

I became leader of a clan around 44 members, and we’ve got problems! We lose almost every war and people donate garbage. How can I fix this? Most people members aren’t responsive in chat. The current clan settings are:

•   Anyone can join
•   2200 required trophies
•   War frequency once a week (though this used to be always, and at least 1 member said he wants this)
•   Clan location: USA (but I think we have people from all around the world)
•   We’re a level 4 clan

In the last war only 38/80 attacked, though we did get crushed pretty quickly. There were things like the co-leader only got 1 star in 2 attacks, should I demote him? All the elders and coleaders are left from the previous leader who quit the clan. These problems have been going on for a while but people aren't leaving.

Comment: You're gonna have to be more selective about who can join as well as be more strict on existing members, if someone doesn't participate, then you'll have to kick them

Comment: just kick worst people and make your group close. Try to talk to clan member that they wanna win gold or not by winning war. If they are not replying kick them and just have loyal one. Demote unnecessary people and try to have loyal member..all the best..:)

Comment: Did you watch the clashcon which was last Saturday (24-Oct-2015)? There was a part of it dedicated to tips for managing and keeping good clans and lasted for about 30 minutes maybe with 5 rather popular clashers. Might be worth watching. It should be on clashofclans' youtube channel and it was after the first clanwar tournament. I would advise starting a clan with a handful of trusted members first (friends you know) and grow slowly, make sure the new members are the players you want, before getting more.

Comment: Do a major purge of members who aren't valuable to you. If people get mad, so be it, they need to understand that its your clan and you make the rules. Also I recommend starting a kik group chat

Comment: @Neffer_23 what's a kik group chat?

Comment: kik is a free messenger app like iMessage but it creates group chats with non iPhone users also. group chats can hold up to 50 people max, making it perfect for CoC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to get more strict, the people in your clan may like you less but if you want to win you've got to set down rules.

If you want to go hardcore (war>clan) you would have to do something like 4-5 stars each war and either get 1 warning or boot straight away.

If you want to go casual (war=clan) but still win give people warnings but still ask for 3+ stars per war.

You may end up with a smaller clan, but that's a smaller clan filled with people who are dedicated.

As you have taken over you (possibly) should demote everybody to member (or co-leaders to just elders) and promote the people YOU trust, not the people the previous leader trusted.

As for donating unless you want to go hardcore the best you can do is warn them and kick them if people never stop complaining about them. If you do want to go hardcore implement the same system as you did for warring, donate what is requested for. And have them demoted/kicked if they do not.

If you are going for casual make sure that the clan members know to notify you that they won't be on (holiday with no internet etc.).